# Does application insights support stateful service in service fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

Does Application Insights support stateful service. All the examples I have see requires that the service be hosted in kestrel for application insight to work.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter what SDK/framework you are using basically.
The .NET SDK can work in any .NET program with network connectivity.
Of course different frameworks get different levels of integration out of the box, so you may have to add more manual tracking calls.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some SF context to Juunas' reply.

Kestrel is a matter of how you host the service. If using ASP.NET and relying on HTTP communication, you can host a Reliable Stateful Services as well using the SF ASP.NET integration. AI supports this sceanrio, as it's just HTTP communication.

If you do not use the ASP.NET integration for SF, and using Service Remoting based communication, AI also has support for this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/10/06/distributed-tracing-in-service-fabric-using-application-insights/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a [.NET SDK for Native Service Fabric Applications](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-servicefabric) which can be used for stateful or stateless as used in the [Service Fabric monitoring tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-monitoring-aspnet)